# Remover linhas de comentários de arquivos TXT

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como remover as tags de comentários de arquivos *TXT* com *PHP*, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Estou com esse problema na leitura de arquivos txt que estão exibindo os comentários.

Código PHP:

```
function extrairDadosNotificacao($NomeArquivo){
      $arquivo = fopen($NomeArquivo, 'r');

      $dados = array();
      while (($buffer = fgets($arquivo, 4096)) !== false) {
          $dados[] = $buffer;
      }
      return $dados;
}

$test = extrairDadosNotificacao("test.txt");


echo "<pre>";
var_dump($test);
```

Arquivo txt :

```
//TEST
//TEST
'test'    1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: alterei, no caso queria saber como remover os comentários do //TEST

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, você pode ler o arquivo num *array* desta forma:

```
$linhas = file($arquivo, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file.php

Depois, basta remover as linhas indesejadas:

```
function naoecomentario($val){
    return '//' != substr($val, 0, 2);
}
$linhasfiltradas = array_filter($linhas, 'naoecomentario');
```

A partir daí pode salvar no disco linha a linha, ou juntar com `implode`.

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php

**Agora,** se for só exibir ou salvar, não precisa nem do `array_filter`, basta isso:

```
foreach($linhasfiltradas as $linha) {
    if('//' != substr($val, 0, 2)) {
       // ... mostra na tela ou salva no arquivo ...
       echo htmlentities($linha)."<br>\n";
    }
}
```

**Importante:** se o arquivo for demasiado grande, pode ser o caso de ler aos pedaços, e ir gravando sem reter tudo na memória. Não entrei em detalhes por não ser aplicavel à maioria dos casos, mas é bom ter isso em mente.

Basicamente se trata de trocar o `file` por leitura linha a linha, e usar a um `if` + `substr` conforme o último exemplo